# How Do I Apply the Cantor-Zassenhaus algorithm to $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, factoring

Recently, I've been trying to implement the Cantor-Zassenhaus algorithm in C++ over $\mathbb{F}_2$. According to this [lecture](http://www.cmi.ac.in/~ramprasad/lecturenotes/comp_numb_theory/lecture11.pdf), the algorithm is basically:

Input is polynomial $f\in\mathbb{F}_q$ with degree $n=rd$ which has $r$ irreducible factors of degree $d$.
Generate a random polynomial $a$ with degree less than $n$.
Let $m=\frac{p^d-1}{2}$
Compute $a'=a^m+1$
If $gcd(a', f)\neq1$, then $gcd(a',f)$ is one of the factors.

Something I don't understand is, why is that particular value for $m$ chosen in the algorithm? Also, $p^d-1$ is not divisible by 2 when $p = 2$. So how could I modify the algorithm so that it still works for the $p = 2$ case?

Comment: The point of using that $m$ is that if $p$ is one of the irreducible degree $d$ factors of $f$, then $a^m$ is congruent to either $0$ (rarely) or, more probably $\pm1$ modulo $p$. The point being that either sign occurs with a 50% probability (minus $\epsilon$ for the off chance that we get remainder zero). With random $a$ you get more or less random distribution of those $\pm1$s (with $p$ ranging over the factors), so with probability approximately $1-(1/2)^{r-1}$ that gcd is a non-trivial factor of $f$.

Comment: This is because $a^m\equiv1\pmod {p(x)}$, if $a$ is a square modulo $p(x)$ and $a^m\equiv-1\pmod p$ if a non.square. BUT, when $p=2$ everything is a square, so we need to do something differently. I am ashamed that I don't know how Cantor & Zassenhaus do it. I can guess that they use trace instead (that would be the first way of getting a random 50-50 split I can think of). So, if $q^d=2^\ell$, then instead of $a'=a^m\pm1$ I would try
$$a'=a+a^2+a^4+\cdots+a^{2^{\ell-1}}.$$ Observe that the calculation of that sum is not too expensive, because you will only need to do repeated squaring.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen post as an answer?

Comment: http://blog.fkraiem.org/2013/12/01/polynomial-factorisation-over-finite-fields-part-3-final-splitting-cantor-zassenhaus-in-odd-characteristic/ seems to confirm your suggestion for $GF(2^k)$