# Relatively simple algorithm for factoring polynomials in $GF(2^k)[x]$ with $32 \leq k \leq 128$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, factoring, polynomial-rings

Is there a relatively simple algorithm for factoring polynomials in $GF(2^k)[x]$ with $32 \leq k \leq 128$?

I like [McEliece's algorithm](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/91b8/d2172d6ceeb99fd548532483aa8f3a99c8e5.pdf) for factoring polynomials in $GF(2)[x]$, because of its simplicity, but the runtime is at least proportional to the cardinality of the coefficient field, so it would be very slow in $GF(2^k)[x]$ for large k.

The polynomials I am working with are all reducible to linear terms $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)\ldots$.

Comment: looks like Cantor-Zassenhaus works.... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636518/how-do-i-apply-the-cantor-zassenhaus-algorithm-to-mathbbf-2